# How to handle constructors without any args? - Java

Tags: java

I have created the following program which creates points on a 2-dimensional plane and is able to calculate the distance between the points:

```
public class Point{
  public double pt1;
  public double pt2;

  Point (double pt1, double pt2){
    if (pt1 == null && pt2 == null){this.pt1 = 0; this.pt2 = 0;}
    this.pt1 = pt1;
    this.pt2 = pt2;
  }
  public double distanceTo(Point that){
    double x = this.pt1 - that.pt1;
    double y = this.pt2 - that.pt2;
    return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Point a = new Point(3, 0); 
    Point b = new Point(0, 4); 
    System.out.println(a.distanceTo(b)); 
    System.out.println((new Point(1, 1)).distanceTo(new Point())); //Check what's wrong here! Why is this throwing an error? How to handle empty args?
  }
}
```

As the last print statement is stated, how can I modify my Point constructor to handle if there are 0 arguments that are passed through (for example "new Point()"). Is the right way to go about this by checking the length of the args? Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: `Point (){this.pt1 = 0;this.pt2 = 0;}`  if you want a `Point` to be `{0,0}` by default.

Comment: Note: The `null` check in your constructor is not necessary, because a `double` can never be `null`.

Comment: Either initialize with default values, or don't supply the constructor at all, why would deny the compiler helping the user?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a constructor to have a default behaviour when parameters are not provided you would rather create a separate default constructor.
This way the fully parameterised constructor is clearer.

```
class Point {
  double pt1;
  double pt2;

  Point(double pt1, double pt2){
    // always set up all parameters
    this.pt1 = pt1;
    this.pt2 = pt2;
  }

  Point(){
    // default constructor calls the parameterised constructor with default values
    this(0.0, 0.0);
  }

  // other methods
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more introduction to your solution; maybe just expanding a bit on the in-line comment?

Comment: Someone may have downvoted it before you added the good explanation.  I upvoted it with your changes; good job.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly! You'll just have to add a default constructor defination.

```
ClassName(){
//Stuff you want to process and return
  }
```